# TFlearn/ Tensorflow way slower than expected

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, deep-learning, numeric

I am working on an engineering problem about numerical optimization. Usually I used metamodel approaches like Kriging - but now I want to try the new popular stuff.
The data here is showing a machine part with 7 geometrical parameters and as a result I get one power value. Later, when the data fits, I want to see if can optimize the part with a simple particle swarm algorithm that works on the net.

I wrote my own simple ANN with several hidden layers with numpy and the performance for small scale nets (e.g. 7,30,30,1) was hundreds of epochs per second. Bigger nets (e.g. 7,999,999,1) experienced an obvious slowdown. Now I want to harness the power of my GPU (Quadro M4000). Here's my code, a modified MNIST example i found online  here https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/dnn.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # Data loading and preprocessing. 7 geometric parameters with one solution (last row) each
    Train =np.array([[0.848,0.994,0.475,0.120,0.141,0.670,0.156,-0.29750],
            [0.761,0.221,0.414,0.825,0.429,0.174,0.804,12.28900],
            [0.915,0.891,0.177,0.936,0.503,0.820,0.028,4.46918],
            [0.730,0.203,0.660,0.065,0.124,0.326,0.183,10.51110],
            [0.071,0.247,0.512,0.568,0.395,0.149,0.881,12.31750],
            [0.650,0.836,0.165,0.712,0.334,0.764,0.134,10.23280],
            [0.144,0.261,0.605,0.208,0.557,0.640,0.281,12.26680],
            [0.584,0.301,0.959,0.460,0.987,0.300,0.107,9.39676],
            [0.384,0.555,0.276,0.755,0.718,0.200,0.249,12.49240],
            [0.278,0.080,0.376,0.857,0.462,0.900,0.559,10.70610],
            [0.740,0.514,0.086,0.968,0.443,0.923,0.641,9.75352],
            [0.483,0.103,0.945,0.547,0.822,0.784,0.614,10.08490],
            [0.871,0.732,0.117,0.881,0.883,0.594,0.759,10.22090],
            [0.334,0.332,0.547,0.392,0.150,0.075,0.726,12.01180],
            [0.558,0.464,0.083,0.486,0.651,0.975,0.065,8.93398],
            [0.154,0.775,0.781,0.047,0.944,0.689,0.676,10.59200],
            [0.616,0.145,0.195,0.337,0.269,0.266,0.746,11.55840],
            [0.260,0.296,0.922,0.005,0.028,0.465,0.379,1.95064],
            [0.005,0.757,0.554,0.731,0.906,0.163,0.581,12.48950],
            [0.542,0.876,0.025,0.138,0.250,0.747,0.783,8.96552],
            [0.353,0.363,0.844,0.175,0.803,0.287,0.905,10.94560],
            [0.785,0.701,0.491,0.067,0.076,0.656,0.079,11.47360],
            [0.826,0.181,0.530,0.789,0.305,0.395,0.843,12.08160],
            [0.450,0.153,0.790,0.609,0.006,0.768,0.626,9.92177],
            [0.212,0.192,0.595,0.245,0.776,0.866,0.093,11.61500],
            [0.066,0.279,0.866,0.219,0.789,0.574,0.899,11.29240],
            [0.037,0.428,0.361,0.564,0.378,0.946,0.967,11.27440],
            [0.690,0.903,0.285,1.000,0.058,0.233,0.476,11.69370],
            [0.027,0.450,0.228,0.899,0.955,0.449,0.346,11.38700],
            [0.240,0.032,0.687,0.372,0.329,0.844,0.309,11.53640],
            [0.187,0.665,0.301,0.423,0.114,0.868,0.216,11.86770],
            [0.505,0.499,0.201,0.737,0.179,0.120,0.484,12.45780],
            [0.578,0.397,0.821,0.661,0.212,0.337,0.036,4.31481],
            [0.949,0.646,0.892,0.586,0.702,0.536,0.416,1.93674],
            [0.885,0.789,0.994,0.312,0.227,0.037,0.350,0.05622],
            [0.957,0.123,0.317,0.848,0.549,0.510,0.705,11.63030],
            [0.110,0.692,0.384,0.269,0.933,0.113,0.423,12.74620],
            [0.127,0.678,0.008,0.351,0.649,0.620,0.860,10.38200],
            [0.228,0.940,0.247,0.099,0.689,0.093,0.956,11.63780],
            [0.403,0.063,0.464,0.904,0.091,0.401,0.288,11.86670],
            [0.976,0.088,0.718,0.966,0.261,0.816,0.992,10.76000],
            [0.801,0.475,0.871,0.510,0.613,0.885,0.261,8.64352],
            [0.710,0.413,0.262,0.299,0.864,0.426,0.517,12.07250],
            [0.421,0.919,0.764,0.627,0.620,0.729,0.539,1.79113],
            [0.446,0.971,0.338,0.692,0.187,0.061,0.121,12.02700],
            [0.861,0.539,0.901,0.319,0.481,0.369,0.231,1.28605],
            [0.367,0.809,0.675,0.112,0.574,0.701,0.200,10.91850],
            [0.288,0.042,0.618,0.264,0.848,0.355,0.513,12.04380]])

    Y = Train[:, 7].reshape([48,1])
    X = np.delete(Train, (7), axis=1)

    Test =np.array([[0.088,0.857,0.448,0.156,0.364,0.487,0.007,12.21500],
            [0.653,0.371,0.645,0.767,0.034,0.526,0.386,11.5270],
            [0.618,0.008,0.573,0.929,0.284,0.556,0.588,11.55110],
            [0.531,0.348,0.109,0.190,0.674,0.985,0.785,9.66132],
            [0.768,0.609,0.744,0.024,0.969,0.009,0.331,9.49345],
            [0.177,0.523,0.974,0.814,0.736,0.611,0.451,9.61419],
            [0.919,0.817,0.057,0.530,0.415,0.467,0.693,10.44850],
            [0.310,0.628,0.804,0.672,0.598,0.244,0.652,10.37430],
            [0.430,0.900,0.480,0.700,0.620,0.300,0.600,11.77790],
            [0.318,0.741,0.142,0.405,0.532,0.189,0.936,11.86930]])

    testY = Test[:, 7].reshape([10,1])
    testX = np.delete(Test, (7), axis=1)    


    # Building deep neural network

    input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 7])
    dense1 = tflearn.fully_connected(input_layer, 70, activation='relu',
                                    regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.001)
    dropout1 = tflearn.dropout(dense1, 0.8)
    dense2 = tflearn.fully_connected(dropout1, 70, activation='tanh',
                                    regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.001)
    dropout2 = tflearn.dropout(dense2, 0.8)
    linear = tflearn.fully_connected(dropout2, 1, activation='linear')

    #Regression using SGD 
    sgd = tflearn.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, lr_decay=0.96, decay_step=100)
    net = tflearn.regression(linear, optimizer=sgd, loss='mean_square',
                                    metric='R2', learning_rate=0.01)
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):       
    # Training
    model = tflearn.DNN(net) 
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=200, validation_set=(testX, testY),batch_size = None,
            show_metric=True, run_id="dense_model")

    print("\nTest prediction")
    print(testY)
    print(model.predict(testX))
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. basically no matter what size of hidden layers i choose i get this kind of performance. Over one second per epoch! Even if it runs on CPU only it should be alot faster, no?

`Training Step: 19  | total loss: 87.36314 | time: 1.019s`

`Training Step: 20  | total loss: 86.11715 | time: 1.013s`

2. I wonder why use "with tf.device('/gpu:0'):" for the complete code crashes with the error message:

   `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node

   'init_3/NoOp': Unknown input node '^is_training/Assign'`

edit: I fixed number 2 with adding those lines:

```
tflearn.init_graph(num_cores=6,gpu_memory_fraction=0.2)
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

The difference between 10 and 10000 nodes is neglectable small ~ 1.1 s vs. 1.7 s so I have to assume there is a major overhead somewhere else going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is that the validation each epoche took so much time. Honestly I didnt expect that because as far as I know its only one foward calculation and shouldnt take that much time. Validate only every n-timesstep changes alot with the following:

```
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=2000, validation_set=(testX, testY),batch_size = None,snapshot_step=100, snapshot_epoch=False,
        show_metric=True, run_id="dense_model")
```